# Can we suggest where to find videos (that may or may not be copyrighted)

Tags: discussion

I'm aware this is always a contentious issue, so I'm seeking guidance.

I've just answered this question: [A man finds some wrapping paper and gives it as a present to his daughter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17763/a-man-finds-some-wrapping-paper-and-gives-it-as-a-present-to-his-daughter/17765#17765)

After reading some guidance on the Stack sites, I chose against linking to a YouTube video I found. This was particularly because I found two videos, one of which was blocked by Warner Bros for copyright reasons. However, rather than linking to the second video I told the OP to simply google "Gift of Gold.avi". If he does that, the video in question is the first response.

Is that kind of linking acceptable? Or is anything of that nature deemed inappropriate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is perfectly acceptable to link to YouTube videos or the like, i.e. a legal video sharing site, not a site which allows copyrighted material.  YouTube has a published mechanism by which a copyright owner can challenge the publishing of their material on the site, and they will take down infringing material.

I would stay away from linking to a site with dubious copyright, e.g. lots of full movies, published for free.

Please note however that questions of the sort .... "where can I find movie x" are definitely off topic.  We are not a file sharing forum.  Where a video clip will enhance a question or answer, this is fine.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'll change my answer to include an actual link then.