# Linking to Youtube

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

so when answering this question

[Why did the dad try to shoot Victoria, and what happens to the real mom?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102583/why-did-the-dad-try-to-shoot-victoria-and-what-happens-to-the-real-mom/102784#102784)

I came across a video on youtube that shows the opening sequence to the movie but its clear someone has recorded their television using a mobile phone or some other recording device. 
I know previous questions have said its acceptable to link to youtube but his looks like blatantly like piracy, so would it still be acceptable to link?

Comment: i saw that but read this and thought it was kind of contradictory https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/can-we-suggest-where-to-find-videos-that-may-or-may-not-be-copyrighted

Comment: I can see why you think they are contradictory.  It's a grey area - its not our responsibility to police YouTube.  They have mechanisms in place to request content is taken down.  That said I wouldn't link to something that is obviously going to break copyright - a full copy of a recent movie for example.  If nothing else its likely that the content will eventually be taken down, rendering the link useless.